# Is there a new keyboard shortcut to open files within Explorer in Visual Studio Code 1.10.2 on Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I used to be able to press Command+Shift+E to focus on the file explorer, and then open the currently selected file to edit with Command+Down on Mac... now it doesn't seem to work anymore in the recent VSCode 1.10.2.

I can workaround it by using the mouse/trackpad to doubleclick the file but it's so inefficient compared to the keyboard.

Is there a new keybinding for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.10.0 was the first version to officially support configurable keybindings to the file explorer. I am not sure if the defaults changed in the update. You can now set them to whatever you'd like.

You'll want to add something similar to the following in your keybinding settings:

```
{ "key": "cmd+shift+e", "command": "workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer" },
{ "key":    "cmd+down", "command": "list.select" },
```

More information about the file explorer keybindings in the [release docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_configurable-explorer-key-bindings), or the vscode keybinding [documentation page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings).